# Recover input of matrix-valued function from observations of a composite scalar function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am faced with the following problem and unsure how to proceed.

Given functions ${\bf M}_1, {\bf M}_2, \dots, {\bf M}_n : {\mathbb R}^n \to {\mathbb R}^{n \times n}$ and a vector ${\bf y} \in {\mathbb R}^n$, define $$ f_i ({\bf x}) := {\bf y}^\top {\bf M}_i({\bf x}) \, {\bf y} $$

and ${\bf f} := \begin{bmatrix} f_1 & f_2 & \dots & f_n \end{bmatrix}^\top$. I would like find the vector field [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) of $\bf f$ via $ {\bf x} = {\bf f} ({\bf x}) $, or, alternatively, via the seemingly weaker condition

$${\bf x} \propto \sum_{i=1}^n f_i({\bf x}) {\bf e}_i$$

where ${\bf e}_i$ is a vector of zeros with a $1$ in the $i$-th entry.

The function ${\bf M}$ can be defined so that its output is a symmetric matrix, if that helps.

This has the flavor of a system of equations or an eigenvalue/eigenvector equation, but with some obvious differences.

Is this problem well-posed? Has anyone seen a problem like this and might know how to go about characterizing the solution? Or otherwise, is there another way to write the problem that might help me see where to start?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I have an exact functional form for $\mathbf M$, but it is quite long. The vector $\mathbf x$ enters several times combinatorially inside an infinite sum (e.g. $\sum_{t=0}^\infty \delta^t (\mathbf A - \mathbf x \mathbf z')^t\dots$), so I thought it easier to see if there's a characterization for general $\mathbf M$ functions

Comment: Thinking of this as a fixed point of a vector field opens the door to some interesting potential properties of the solution

Comment: The more general the function, the less one can say